# how to set permanent background of all activities?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using following code:

```
Public void xyz(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
}

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode){
        case 0:
            data.getDataString();
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(_activity.getContentResolver(), data.getDataString());
                    RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.might);
                    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    bg.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch blocke.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch blocke.printStackTrace();
                }
            }                   
            break;
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. It sets Background for only one Activity.
2. After `onDestroy()` method, It sets default Background on restart.

Comment: learn to format your code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: You can write an Activity class that is a super class of all your other Activities

Comment: You can store the url of the selected image in a singleton class/SharedPreferences and load it when the Activity is created. Probably you can even use the cache of libs like Picasso to avoid loading the image if it is still in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save image to internal storage (put in onactivityresult)

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
  try {
 outputStream = openFileOutput("filename.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            outputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

//load image and set to background(onsatrtactivity)

```
try {
        FileInputStream l = openFileInput("filename.jpg");
        Bitmap A = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(l);
        LinearLayout bg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutid);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), A);
        bg.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

thanks Marcin Jedynak!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use one MainActivity. Then, Use fragments as screens in it. Give your color or background drawable to MainActivity's layout. But, do following for all fragment's layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
```

First two `00`'s are for making background transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Rupinderjeet asnwer was correct. it can make you work by default background.

But **here is an easy and best way to do this.**

make an style in your `style.xml` placed in `values`

```
<style name="DefaultBackgroundTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_bitmap</item> 
</style>
```

Change `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light` by your app theme

you can put `color`, `bitmaps` or `drawables` as well here.

and inside your manifest class change your theme by

```
<activity
    android:name="yourActivityName"
    android:theme="@style/DefaultBackgroundTheme" />
```

Hope this helps you.